# Quantum Spin Hall Effect : Dimensional reduction from Chern Simons 3 form

Tags: quantum-spin, topology, topological-insulators, chern-simons-theory

I have a problem matching the two definitions of the Z2 topological invariant for a 2D system, assuming Sz symmetry.
I can either define it from 1D to 2D, as a Chern number per spin:
$$
C_{\rm s} = \frac{C_{\uparrow}-C_{\downarrow}}{2}
$$
where $C_{\uparrow}$ (resp. $C_{\downarrow}$) is the first Chern number of the hamiltonian restricted to the $\uparrow$ (resp. $\downarrow$) spin sector.

Or I can use the Chern Simons 3 form:
$$
\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int{\rm d}^3 k {\rm Tr}\left(dA\wedge A+\frac{2}{3}A\wedge A \wedge A\right)
$$
Can dimensional reduction be applied to pass from the 3D definition to the "spin Chern number" definition ?

How does one perform the $k_z$ integration in the 2D system ?

Where does the spin appear in the 3D formula ?